# Telegram bot can't delete messages that was sent 48h ago despite of it has permissions

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a bot that publish some messages in a supergroup. It's an admin and it has can_delete_messages, but it can't delete old messages (more than 48h ago). Code, id_message and id_group are correct: it can delete recent messages. The error is: 400 Bad Request: message can't be deleted.

Recap of infos:
1. Bot is admin of supergroup and it has can_delete_messages permission.
2. Code, id_messages and id_group are right
3. Bot can delete recent messages  (less than 48h ago)
4. Messages were sent by bot
5. Error is: 400 Bad Request: message can't be deleted

I use this simple code with TelegramBotApi library for Java:

```
DeleteMessage delete = new DeleteMessage();
delete.setChatId(chatId);
delete.setMessageId(messageId);
try {
    execute(delete);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage

> A message can only be deleted if it was sent less than 48 hours ago.

Comment: If the bot has can_delete_messages permission in a supergroup or a channel, it can delete any message there

It means bot can also delete old messages, isn't it?

Comment: Nope, the docs say that it can delete only messages sent less than 48 hours ago.